# Websphere MQ: Who should manage the backout queues

Tags: java, ibm-mq, backout

Let's say that my configuration details are:

- 1 PubSub that publishes messages to a MQ Topic.
- 2 different consumers applications.
- 1 topic subscription per consumer.
- 1 queue per subscription.
- And finally 1 backout queue per queue.

Who should manage the backout queue content and determine what should be republished?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to look at is: Why the messages are ending up in back-out queue in the first place?

1) Is it the JMS Client that is backing out the messages because the messages are not in a valid format?

2) Is it that consumer application is rolling back messages due to an error in the application?

If the problem is #1 above, you need to look at producer applications and determine why message format is invalid. If it's #2, then you need to look at your application logic.

Finally you need to have an application that looks at back-out queue and takes appropriate corrective action to put the messages back into subscription queue.

Answer (score 0):

The application owning the backout queue should *always* manage the backout queue.  While this is true in the general case, it is easpecially true in the case of pub/sub because it is impossible for the publisher(s) to know who all the subscribers are and manage their backout queues across the entire MQ estate.

An argument against this is that a particular application design ***does*** know in advance the recipients of the messages.  My response is that this describes a distribution list and not pub/sub which was specifically designed to decouple publishers from subscribers.

An alternative to the implementation you described is to use a common backout queue on all subscriptions.  You make a model queue specifying the intended common backout queue and specify that model in the topic object.  New subscriptions then automatically route backout messages to the common backout queue.  Then a central process or the publisher can manage the backed out messages.

Note that this implementation still follows my advice that the application owning the backout queue should *always* manage the backout queue because in this case the application managing backout messages owns the queue.